# Powershell Move file from directory to subdirectory based on filename

Tags: regex, windows, powershell, pattern-matching, batch-processing

I would like to do all 8k+ files at once using the pattern since the left 5 chars of the file matches the right 5 of the sub-directory to move to.

This works one by one:

```
move-item -path X:\"Property Files"\05165*.pdf -destination X:\"Property Files"\"* -- 05165";
move-item -path X:\"Property Files"\05164*.pdf -destination X:\"Property Files"\"* -- 05164";
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a one-liner, assuming destination folder already exist:

```
Get-ChildItem "X:\Property Files\*.PDF" | 
 ForEach { move -path $_ -destination ($_.directoryname +"\* -- "+ $_.Name.substring(0,5))}
```

Using only the filename, you just extract the first five chars (`substring(0,5)`), then use it as the end of the folder to match.
`$_.Directoryname` assume destination folder is a subfolder of the source path.

Comment: thank you so much. It worked perfectly. I tried a couple of files using the 5 digit in front of the * before I let it go on the entire directory and when it tested out as working I put the asterisk only back in and hit enter. It took about an hour on my machine, but that was much faster than before. Appreciate the time savings. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you're on the right path with the whole RegEx tag here. What I did is look for everything until the last backslash, then captured 5 digits, then everything that isn't a backslash until the end of the line, and only returned the captured group. I set that as a variable `$ItemNumber`, and used that in the destination. I ran that on a ForEach loop for everything in the target source folder. Here's the code I ended up with:

```
ForEach($File in (GCI "X:\Property Files\*.PDF")){
$ItemNumber = $File.Fullname -replace ".+?\\(\d{5})[^\\]*$", "`$1"
move-item -path X:\"Property Files"\05165*.pdf -destination X:\"Property Files"\"* -- $ItemNumber"
}
```

You could do it through the pipe if you wanted, like this:

```
GCI "X:\Property Files\*.PDF"|%{move-item -path X:\"Property Files"\05165*.pdf -destination X:\"Property Files"\"* -- $($_.Fullname -replace ".+?\\(\d{5})[^\\]*$", "`$1")"}
```

But that gets kind of long, and some people really don't like that long of a single line.

That RegEx can be tested [here](http://regex101.com/r/vY2cK1), plus it breaks it all down. (link to regex101.com explanation)

Comment: Appreciate your help also. I was looking for a batch process that didn't require naming each file so this didn't exactly fit the bill. Good to know about the regex site.

Comment: This shouldn't rename the files at all, just move them, but I'm glad you found a solution that works for you.